# Is this Angular 2 project structure compatible with angular cli?

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, angular-cli

I'm using the following tutorial: http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2017/02/22/mean-with-angular-2-user-registration-and-login-example-tutorial

When I tried to use ng serve (instead of npm start as the tutorial suggests) I ran into the following error:

'Unable to find "@angular/cli" in devDependencies.'

Essentially I'm asking if it's possible to make this project compatible with the angular cli and if so how?

My end goal is to try and see if I could host this on heroku, and I'd like to use the "ng build" command. Is there maybe a way to get around this and host not using the angular cli?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

ng serve is angular cli command. Angular CLI is a command line interface created for simplifying angular project setup.

Your project has to be Angular CLI project to be compatible with Angular CLI:)

Setup is very easy:

1. Install Angular CLI [more info here](https://cli.angular.io/). For you the one important command is `npm install -g @angular/cli` which will install Angular CLI globally.
2. Run `ng new project_name` which will create and setup all you need for angular 5 project (if you use the current angular cli).
3. From the project folder run `ng serve`

If you want to generate new component run `ng g c component-name`
If you want to generate new module run `ng g m module-name`
If you want to generate new service run `ng g s service-name`